# How can I prevent access to my subversion repository

Tags: svn, authorization

I would like to prevent people from accessing my experimental branch

I have restarted and stopped the subversion service after making these changes.

I have the following in my Authz file:

```
[aliases]
# joe = /C=XZ/ST=Dessert/L=Snake City/O=Snake Oil, Ltd./OU=Research Institute/CN=Joe Average

[groups]
# harry_and_sally = harry,sally
# harry_sally_and_joe = harry,sally,&joe
CMds = DL,JD,MA

# [/foo/bar]
# harry = rw
# &joe = r
# * =

# [repository:/baz/fuz]
# @harry_and_sally = rw
# * = r


[Client:/Branches/Experimental]
@CMds = ~r
@CMds = ~w
```

I would like to prevent people from accessing the experimental branch, but it appears that they still can

Here is the URL for the experimental branch (from the SVN Repo browser )

```
svn://<serverIP>/Client/Branches/Experimental
```

So I changed this:

```
[Client:/Branches/Experimental]
@CMds = ~r
@CMds = ~w
```

To this:

```
[Client:/Branches/Experimental]
@CMds =
```

And there is still no effect ?

I am wondering if the repository name is correct? 
Should it be:

```
[Client:/Branches/Experimental]
```

or

```
[/Client/Branches/Experimental]
```

or ??

Thanks

Comment: autz-rules are applied on the fly, restart not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I always define minimal ACL for `[/]` path in authz-file, [because](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)

> By default, nobody has any access to any repository at all. That means
>   that if you're starting with an empty file, you'll probably want to
>   give at least read permission to all users at the roots of the
>   repositories.

2. **No access** for group in good syntax is `@CMds =`
3. There are `r` and `rw` access-types **only**, `~w` rule is, obviously, ignored and `~r` means <strike>"Write access enabled"</strike>also **nothing**

Selection is mine

> In your authorization rules, prefixing **a username, alias, group
>   name, or authentication class token with a tilde character** will
>   cause Subversion to apply the rule to users who do not match the rule

i.e. *you haven't any ACLs* really defined for your path

Comment: Thank you... does this look right for the repository name:  [Client:/Branches/Experimental]

Comment: @user3174075 - if `Client` is single-repository root, then yes `[Client:/` is correct token. Check `svn ls -R ^/Branches/Experimental` vs `svn ls -R ^/branches/experimental` if your Server isn't Windoze and **case-sensitive**, get **proper names**